# OpenCV face detection with Haar model gets stuck

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I am trying to use the opencv's CascadeClassifier for face detection.
Below is a simplified code from tutorial on [opencv docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html), which I am running.

The problem I have is that the call to `CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale()` won't return (at least not after 20mins on the first frame). What could possibly cause this behaviour and how to fix it?

When I run the same code with the pre-trained LBP model, the classifier runs fast, without any problems. When I however uncomment the `equalizeHist()` call, as it is used in the tutorial, the LBP model gets stuck, similarly to the Haar model.

In answers to a similar questions, I have read that the classifier can take awfully long, when there is no face present.
With the equalized histogram my face on cam became somewhat overexposed, due to dark background. Maybe this could be part of the problem?

```
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
    if(!face_cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"))
        return -1;

    VideoCapture capture(0);
    if (!capture.isOpened())
        return -1;

    UMat frame, frame_gray;

    for (;;) {
        capture >> frame;
        if (!frame.empty()) {
            cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            //equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);    // uncomment and LBP gets stuck too

            std::vector<Rect> faces;
            face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

            for(size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i) {
                Point center(faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5);
                ellipse(frame, center, Size( faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0);
            }
        }

        imshow("Face detection", frame);

        if(waitKey(10) > 0)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how many stages does your classifier use? can you add your classifier.xml? did you train with traincascade or haarcascade binary?

Comment: I didn't train the classifiers, I used the [pre-trained models](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades), that came with the build. This is the [one I used (xml)](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml), having 22 stages. The [LBP classifier](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml) has 20 stages.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39559211/5294258)

Comment: what hardware are you using? Did you try to remove CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE

Comment: @sturkmen that was the problem. Thank you guys.