# OpenCV shows gray window (face detection example)

Tags: c++, opencv

I am currently working on object detection and before diving in I just tried the example demo tutorial from OpenCV. (You can see the tutorial code here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/objectDetection/objectDetection.cpp).

So, my problem is when I build the program, I see a gray frame as detection window. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894451/opencv-shows-gray-window) is a solution for python but I tried this solution and it did not work for me.

[The resulted screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jPh0.jpg) can be seen from this link.

Thanks

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/39559211/5294258

Comment: Thanks !! Perfectly works

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are calling `detectAndDisplay` directly wihtout using the same `main` function.

Just add Add `cv::waitKey()` at the end of the `detectAndDisplay` function.

Comment: Thank you for your response but actually, I have tried this solution since [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894451/opencv-shows-gray-window) says that, but the screen is still gray :(

Comment: @alpay Did you exactly copy the code from the source without any edit?

Comment: I exactly copied the code and run it as console application